Pwa - app on android phone on closing the keyboard is registering a double click
When I open the keyboard of the texfield - the ui moves up with the keyboard and when I touch outside of the keyboard to close it - it is registering a click to the element which was there in that position before opening the keyboard
This issue is happening only in android phones, it works fine in ios
when touched on the black spot marked in screenshot 2 it closes the keyboard but also registers a click on the element which is in exactly at the position in screenshot 1
I am using material ui - tried changing all the heights from px to vh and tried some css changes by fixing the position but it is still behaving that way

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
